# Cannot assign a reference that has a deleted copy constructor?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, copy-constructor, move-assignment-operator

I'm in a situation where I need to implement Move Constructor and Move-Assignment Operator for a class which holds a reference to an object with a deleted Copy Ctor and Copy-Assignment Operator, basically looks like this:

```
class MoveOnlyThing
{
public:
    MoveOnlyThing() = default;
    MoveOnlyThing(const MoveOnlyThing&) = delete;
    MoveOnlyThing& operator=(const MoveOnlyThing&) = delete;
};

class Holder
{
public:
    Holder(MoveOnlyThing& t)
    : mThing(t)
    {
    }
    
    Holder(Holder&& other)
    : mThing(other.mThing)
    {
    }
    
    Holder& operator=(Holder&& other)
    {
        mThing = other.mThing;
        return *this;
    }
    
    MoveOnlyThing& mThing;
};
```

Now, the problem is, the assignment of `mThing = other.mThing;` is emitting an error:

```
main.cpp:40:16: error: overload resolution selected deleted operator '='
        mThing = other.mThing;
        ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:20:12: note: candidate function has been explicitly deleted
    MoveOnlyThing& operator=(const MoveOnlyThing&) = delete;
           ^
```

Two questions are raised;

1. How do we deal with this? Implement the Move Constructor, and then use this to implement the Move-Assignment Operator?
2. I didn't realize that the compiler would generate a copy in this case when re-assigning an existing reference. Who can explain that?

Comment: You can't assign a reference. Only initialize.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of `mThing = other.mThing;`.  It does not mean "Assign a new value to the reference `mThing`", it means "Assign a new value to (the object pointed to by `mThing`)".  References perform indirection implicitly, **any time you use the name of a reference you actually get the object it is pointing to**.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes that is correct, so actually the reason its trying to invoke the copy constructor is to assign to the *original object* thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You need `std::move()` in order to invoke `MoveOnlyThing`'s move assignment operator: `mThing = std::move(other.mThing);`